# How to take powers in validator

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program, smart-contract

I was trying to implement some El Gamal cryptography in plutus, basic verification of statements. But while trying to implement an efficient modular exponential function I noticed that the current `PlutusTx.Prelude` does not even provide a simple power function `(^)`. Digging even deeper I saw that the `PlutusTx.Prelude` only povides an `even` function and not even an `odd` function. How can I contribute to add these function to `PlutusTx.Prelude`?

Is my implementation correct? I import `Plutus.Prelude` as `Prel`. Do I also need to add the template haskell `inlinable` pragma if I make this a library?

```
power :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
power x n |(n==1) = x
        | Prel.even n       = (power x ( Prel.divide n 2))*(pow x ( Prel.divide n 2)) 
        | Prel.even (n-1)   = x * (power x (n-1))

expMod :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer
expMod b e m
    | b == 1    = b
    | e == 0    = 1
    | e == 1    = b `Prel.modulo` m
    | even e    = let p = expMod b (e `Prel.divide` 2) m `Prel.modulo` m
                   in (power p (2::Integer)) `Prel.modulo` m
    | otherwise = (b * expMod b (e-1) m) `Prel.modulo` m
```

which seems to compile without the pragma in a validator.

Answer (score 1):

Try this function:

```
power x n
    | n == 0  =  1
    | x == 0  =  0
    | even n = ( power x (n 'div' 2) ) * ( power x (n 'div' 2) )
    | otherwise n = x * ( power x ((n - 1) 'div' 2)) * ( power x ((n - 1) 'div' 2) )
```

Look at the type signature for `even`:
`even :: (Integral a) => a -> Bool`.
`odd` has a similar signature.

So you can see that `even` and `odd` take any type of the `Integral` typeclass and evaluate it. Then look at the signature for `/`:
`(/) :: (Fractional a) => a -> a -> a`.

`/` takes only `Fractional` types, not `Integral` ones. It's impossible for one type to be evaluated by both those functions. In this case, there's an easy fix: use `div` instead of `/`.

Note that if you use `div` as an infix function (place it between the arguments) you'll need to put backticks around `div`.

Comment: Thank you for correcting my bad cases, but note that the use of odd here is not allowed since `PlutusTx.Prelude` does not have this.

Comment: Well in this case should `otherwise` (instead of `odd`) also work, but an `odd` would be also great. 